# FE Searchfield in simpleblog extension doesn't work

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

I am trying to going through the book "TYPO3 Extbase - Modern Extension Development" from P. Lobacher. There I am on the point with the searchfield. Here my Editor (PHPStorm) tells me that $search isn't defined.

I have a listAction with:

```
/**
 * @internal param string $search
 */
public function listAction() {
    if ($this->request->hasArgument('search')){
        $search = $this->request->getArgument('search');
    }
    $limit = ($this->settings['blog']['max']) ?: NULL;
    $this->view->assign('blogs', $this->blogRepository->findSearchForm($search,$limit));
    $this->view->assign('search', $search);
}
```

In my repository i try to setup a query like that:

```
/**
 * @param string $search
 * @param int $limit
 * @return array|\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface
 */
public function findSearchForm($search,$limit) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->matching(
        $query->like('title','%'.$search.'%')
    );
    $query->setOrderings(array('title' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING));
    $limit = (int)$limit; if ($limit > 0) {
        $query->setLimit($limit);
    }
    return $query->execute();
}
```

In my list view i have the searchform like that:

```
<f:form action="list" additionalAttributes="{role:'form'}"> <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <f:form.textfield name="search" value="{search}" class="form-control" /> <f:form.submit value="Search!" class="btn-xs btn-primary" />
    </div> </div>
</f:form>
```

If i change the assign to the view in my listAction to:

```
$this->view->assign('blogs', $this->blogRepository->findSearchForm('Testblog',$limit));
```

Then he shows me the blogs with the titlefragment "Testblog" in it. But dynamically it won't work.

I am using TYPO3 v8.5.1

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

at first you should change the $limit line because its hard to read. Change it to:

```
$limit = $this->settings['blog']['max'] ? $this->settings['blog']['max'] : 0;
```

I changed NULL to 0 because in the repository annotation the parameter should be an integer.

Then you should also change the two assign() functions to an assignMultiple()-Array.

Have you ever debugged $search in your controller using

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($search);
```

Because your  is not bound to an object, you are may not able to get $search with getArgument(). Can you please give us the rendered HTML output of that form field?

**EDIT:** Because of your search you may not cache the list action. Change list action in ext_localconf.php to NOT CACHED.

Comment: Hi Paul, thx for your answer. I've changed NULL to 0 and  Then i have debugged $search and the result is: '0' (1 chars)

With the assignMultiple()-Array you mean something like: $this->view->assign(array(('blogs', $this->blogRepository->findSearchForm($search,$limit)),('search', $search))) ? Or what did you mean? 

The rendered HTML is: <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tx_cfsimpleblog_bloglisting[search]">

EDIT: I've already put in to "NOT CACHED"

thx for your help.